# Composite PK. Generate new sequential key for each unique other composite key parts

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The table `Parent` has `parent_id varchar` as primary key. The table `Children` has `parent_id varchar, sub_id number(2,0)` as its primary key and `parent_id` is foreign key which links to `Parent`. How to starting generating `sub_id` back from `0` for each unique `parent_id`. For example

```
---------------
Parent        |
---------------
parent_id     |
---------------
p1            |
---------------
p2            |
---------------
```

If I add 3 children with foreign key (part of composite primary key) `parent_id=p1` their `sub_id` should be 0, 1, 2. Then when I add some more children with `parent_id=p2` their `sub_id` should start from 0 back again, not from 3. Is there any DB feature like this? Or should this be done with coding?

Comment: What should happen if you remove a row with sub_id = 1? This feature should convert the corresponding sub_id = 2 to 1? Why do you need this sub_id?

Comment: As far as i know it has to be done with coding, but if you need unique ids i strongly recommend not to do that and use an oralce sequence instead, though your numbers will of course not start at zero again. Its a hell lot of unnecessary work trying to keep ids unique by yourself ( care for simultaneous inserts i.e.). Your application shouldn't care if the first subid starts with 0 or 113. If for whatever reason you have to visualize the ids you can always display them as 0,1,2 even if they are other numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with a database feature, no. However, you should seriously re-consider *why* you need to do this - and preferably stop.

You will have to do this in code, which means:

- in order to add a record you are going to have to select from the table to find out the greatest `sub_id` or to find whether the `parent_id` exists, before inserting
- in order to update a record you're going to have to determine whether you're updating the `sub_id` and move all the others around if you are
- in order to delete a record you're going to have move *all* the `sub_id`s greater than the one you've deleted after the deletion has happened.

This is not pretty, more than doubles the amount of work you have to do every time you modify the table and significantly complicates your code.

It would be far more usual to have a normal, incrementing, sequence for the column `sub_id` rather than re-setting it for every parent. You should be able to do all calculations off that. If you really feel like you have to have something that resets create a view on top of this table and generate your cyclical sequence on the fly, using the analytic function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100):

```
select parent_id, row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by sub_id) as sub_id
  from ...
```

Comment: I also think this is terribly bad idea. But I did not design the database, just writing some code that works with it. I asked to change it, thankfully they agreed.